# Silverlight 4 - Declare/Populate a control's collection property via XAML?

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, collections, user-controls

First of all I wanted to thank all of you for all the wonderful input you have provided. I have to admit - StackOverflow has been the greatest peer-tutor resource available, and as such it has provided me with more knowledge, than ... the 4 years in "college". Thanks!

I am working with a control that has a property which is a collection of objects.

```
public class UserParameter
{
    string DisplayName { get; set; }
    string Property { get; set; }
    string Type { get; set; }
}

public class ParameterBuilder: UserControl
{
    private ObservableCollection<UserParameter> parameters;

    //alright - this is really dependency property.
    //described as property just for simplicity.
    public ObservableCollection<UserParamter> Parameters
    {
        get { return this.parameters; }
        set { this.parameters = value; }
    }
}
```

So the meat of this question is to figure out how to create this collection in Xaml. For example:

```
<custom:ParameterBuilder Name="Parameter">
    <custom:ParameterBuilder.Parameters>
        <custom:UserParameter DisplayName="Test 0" Property="Size"  Type="String"/>
        <custom:UserParameter DisplayName="Test 1" Property="Value" Type="Decimal"/>
    </custom:ParameterBuilder.Parameters>
</custom:ParameterBuilder>
```

Is this possible and if so, how do I go about doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, collection properties should be plain old (non-dependency) read-only properties. The XAML parser is smart enough to add items to collection properties. For example:

```
public class ParameterBuilder: UserControl
{
    private ObservableCollection<UserParameter> parameters = new ObservableCollection<UserParameter>();

    // Don't make it a dependency property
    public ObservableCollection<UserParamter> Parameters
    {
        get { return this.parameters; }
    }
}
```

And you could use it like you describe:

```
<custom:ParameterBuilder Name="Parameter">
    <custom:ParameterBuilder.Parameters>
        <custom:UserParameter DisplayName="Test 0" Property="Size"  Type="String"/>
        <custom:UserParameter DisplayName="Test 1" Property="Value" Type="Decimal"/>
    </custom:ParameterBuilder.Parameters>
</custom:ParameterBuilder>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using .NET 4.0 you should be able to reference generics with the x:TypeArguments parameter ([part of the XAML2009 spec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee956431.aspx)) - so the Observable Collection in your argument would be declared like:

```
<ObservableCollection x:TypeArguments="UserParameter">
    <l:UserParameter DisplayName="Test 0" Property="Size" Type="String" />
    <l:UserParameter DisplayName="Test 1" Property="Value" Type="Decimal" />
</ObservableCollection />
```